# React bootstrap: How to pass an array to options in Form.Control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using Form.Control to create a drop down list and I would like to make the list dynamic. My code looks like this:

```
render() {
 return (

 <Form.Control as="select" value={this.state.inputval} onChange={this.updateinputval}>
  <option value={myArray[0].value}> myArray[0].value </option>
  <option value={myArray[1].value}> myArray[1].value </option>
 </Form.Control>

 )
}
```

Obviously this only works when `myArray` has two elements. I would like to find a way to pass `myArray` into the `options` of 'Form.Control' dynamically. I have found answers in here on how to do it with `Select` but it does not seem to work with `Form.Control as ="select"` as I have here.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to render a dynamic list of elements is to map an array:

```
render() {
 return (
 <Form.Control as="select" value={this.state.inputval} onChange={this.updateinputval}>
  {myArray.map(opt => (
    <option value={opt.value}>{opt.value}</option>
  ))}
 </Form.Control>
 )
}
```

React will ask you to provide a unique `key` prop for the mapped elements. This should ideally be a random id string, but you can add the index of the mapped array `myArray.map((opt, i) => ...` as a fallback while developing (this is also the default value which it uses when you do not provide one).

Answer (score 1):

The [React docs have a section for lists & keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) that will help you solve this. I have included an example for you:

```
const myArray = ["Moo Moo", "Burt", "Little Kitty", "Juan"]

  const options = myArray.map((item) => {
    return (
      <option key={item} value={item}>
        {item}
      </option>
    )
  })

return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.SelectCustom">
              <Form.Label>Custom select</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control as="select" custom>
                {options}
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
```

If it's an `array` type, then mapping `{item.value}` will not work, since there are not key/value pairs in an array, just values.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer